# UIDocumentInteractionController on the detailView

Tags: ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I'm previewing a file using `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but it is occupying all the area of the iPad. I would like it to appear on the detail view of the split view controller. I've checked that the `UIView` of my view controller doesn't occupy all the screen. Any ideas? I checked that the `documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:` is called.

```
-(void)requestExecutedWithSuccess:(Model *)model {
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docInteractionCont = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:model.filePath]];
    self.docInteractionController = docInteractionCont;
    self.docInteractionController.delegate = self;
    BOOL attachmentShown = [self.docInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    ...
}

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return [self navigationController];
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view.frame;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just returning a smaller CGRect using CGRectMake()?

Comment: Yes, I tried that in the method -(CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller, but it still occupies all the iPad screen.

Comment: I am also having this issue, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: did you able to find any solutions?